# Does Git warn me if a shorthand commit ID can refer to 2 different commits?

Tags: git

If `cee157` can refer to 2 different commit IDs, such as

`cee157eb799af829a9a0c42c0915f55cd29818d4` and `cee1577fecf6fc5369a80bd6e926ac5f864a754b`

will Git warn me if I type in `git log cee157`?  (or Git 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48) allows me to type in `git log cee1`).

I think it should, although I can't find any authoritative source that says it would.

Comment: See `man gitrevisions`, which at least implies a warning will be given since it states that you can name a revision with its full SHA1-1 name or "a leading substring that is unique within the repository".

Comment: do you have 17 different commits? just try `git log c` ... and see.

Comment: In ELL, I would probably flag this as [general-reference]

Comment: @djechlin I need at least 4 digits. `git log abc` says `fatal: ambiguous argument 'abc': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.` even if I have a unique SHA1 starting with `abc`. Doesn't work with 1-2-3 digits, 4 seems to be the minimum. Tested in Windows (1.8.1) and Mac (1.9.1).

Comment: @janos That is because [environment.h](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/environment.h) defines `minimum_abbrev` to a value of `4`.

Comment: Not only Git warns you, but stating with Git 2.11+ (Q4 2016), it will list the possible candidates! See "[How to disambiguate an ambiguous abbreviated sha1 in git](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39930978/6309)"

Answer (score 168, accepted):

It should give you something like this:

```
$ git log cee157
error: short SHA1 cee157 is ambiguous.
error: short SHA1 cee157 is ambiguous.
fatal: ambiguous argument 'cee157': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

I just tested this on a real Git repository, by finding commits with duplicate prefixes like this:

```
git rev-list master | cut -c-4 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head
```

This takes the list of revisions in `master`, cuts out the first 4 characters and throws away the rest, count the duplicates and sort numerically. In a my relatively small repository of ~1500 commits I found quite a few revisions with a common 4-digit prefix. I chose a 4-digit prefix because that seems to be the shortest legal length supported by Git. (Doesn't work with 3 digits or less, even if not ambiguous.)

Btw this was not a typo, I don't know why the error message about ambiguous SHA1 appears twice, regardless of the number of duplicate SHA1 (tried with 2 and 3):

```
error: short SHA1 cee157 is ambiguous.
error: short SHA1 cee157 is ambiguous.
```

(Both on `stderr`. Actually the entire output is on `stderr`, nothing on `stdout`.)

Tested in Windows:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.8.1.msysgit.1
```

I think it's safe to say that if your version is >= 1.8.1, Git *will* warn you of duplicates. (It will refuse to operate with duplicates.) I would guess that much older versions worked this way too.

**UPDATE**

When testing this, you need a minimum of 4-digit SHA1, because of `int minimum_abbrev = 4` in [environment.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/environment.c). (Thanks [@devnull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2235132/devnull) for pointing that out!)

Comment: Does the error appear twice even when there are more than two commits with matching prefixes?

Comment: @Nit yes, even when there are 3 dups, the message appears twice. Updated my answer to clarify that.

Comment: Given the structure of the git source code, it looks like one of the two outputs is a warning, and the other one an error.  Not certain, though.

Comment: @MarkHurd both on stderr. Actually the entire output is on stderr, nothing on stdout. (which makes sense)

Answer (score 63):

The original poster states:

> I think it should, although I can't find any authoritative source that
>   says it would.

**The authoritative source can be found in the source code,** [`get_short_sha1()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/sha1_name.c).

Quoting [this](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/sha1_name.c#L341):

```c
if (!quietly && (status == SHORT_NAME_AMBIGUOUS))
    return error("short SHA1 %.*s is ambiguous.", len, hex_pfx);
```

and [this](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/sha1_name.c#L201):

```c
if (!ds->candidate_checked)
    /*
     * If this is the only candidate, there is no point
     * calling the disambiguation hint callback.
     *
     * On the other hand, if the current candidate
     * replaced an earlier candidate that did _not_ pass
     * the disambiguation hint callback, then we do have
     * more than one objects that match the short name
     * given, so we should make sure this one matches;
     * otherwise, if we discovered this one and the one
     * that we previously discarded in the reverse order,
     * we would end up showing different results in the
     * same repository!
     */
    ds->candidate_ok = (!ds->disambiguate_fn_used ||
                        ds->fn(ds->candidate, ds->cb_data));

if (!ds->candidate_ok)
    return SHORT_NAME_AMBIGUOUS;
```

Moreover, [tests](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/t1512-rev-parse-disambiguation.sh) also exist to ensure that the feature works as expected.