# Determing the base SHA of a .patch file

Tags: git, git-patch

I have a .patch file with two commits in it:

```
From 6551a3bb
From <redacted>
Date: Tue, 23 Jun 2015 13:42:58 -0700
Subject: <redacted>

From 224fbe
From: <redacted>
Date: Tue, 30 Jun 2015 21:15:16 +0100
Subject: <redacted>
```

How can I tell what SHA the patch was generated from? Assume I know the branch.

Comment: Do you mean how to disambiguate 6551a3bb? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27428441/how-to-disambiguate-an-ambiguous-abbreviated-sha1-in-git)?

Comment: @VonC no I have a patch but am not sure what commit the HEAD was on when it was generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but am not sure what commit the HEAD was on when it was generated

Looking at [`git format-patch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch), the patch was generated in a way which included 224fbe and 6551a3bb:

- either by specifying a range of commits which includes those two.
  In that case, HEAD could have been anywhere.
- or by specifying a `<since>` commit, where are included the commits leading to the tip of the current branch that are not in the history that leads to the `<since>`.
  In that sec ond case, HEAD might have been `224fbe`